# How to prevent a ligature at one, specific place?

Tags: html, css, utf-8, ligature

In general I like ligatures, they make texts easier to read. I want to enable them on all of my HTML-page.

However there is this one word `Hanftierheft` (it is german, and a compond word of `Hanf` and `Tier` and `Heft`). I *do not want* a ligature for `...nfti...`, but I *want* a ligature for `...eft`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro');
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
Hanftierheft
```

How can I tell my browser to generally *use* ligatures, but not in that, one, specific case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the entity for the [zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) character, and write the word in your HTML code as `Hanf&zwnj;tierheft`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville');

body {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hanf&zwnj;tierheft</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's it! I reused @Maharkus ' awesome example code to have a working example for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `span` and give it `font-variant-ligatures: none;`:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville');

body {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
}

p {
  font-size: 50px;
}

span {
  font-variant-ligatures: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Han<span>fti</span>erheft</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome example code! I reused it for to make my question more clear.

Comment: @slartidan No problem. Doesn't that solve your issue, though?

Comment: I would guess, that the intermediate span tag could be an impediment for search engines, etc. However I have no hard proof this this yet. Anyways: this is an easy to understand, working solution to my issue!

Comment: Well without changing the HTML I don't see any solutions that aren't incredibly messy, ha. Maybe there is some way using Javascript.